# Find symmetry distinct pairs on a Matrix

Tags: matrix, graph, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix, jung

I have a square-planar lattice represented as an NxN grid Graph. Is there any way in Jung to get a symmetric pair of a specific vertex (given the axis of symmetry). Example: 8->0, 5->3.
My goal is to get distinct pairs of nodes. Since pairs (4,1), (4,7), (4,3) and (4,5) are essentially the same. (1,3) would be the same as (3,7) etc. Perhaps some algorithm can be performed on a matrix and then translated to the Graph.

[image: 3x3 example]

Answer (score 0):

General graphs aren't really particularly well-suited to this sort of thing, because they don't have a built-in notion of rows, columns, symmetry about an axis, etc.; they're all about topology, not geometry.

If you really want something like this, you should either create a subtype of Graph that has the operations you want, and create an implementation to match, or just create the corresponding matrix (and a mapping from matrix locations to graph nodes) and do the operations on that matrix instead.

Answer (score 0):

So far I was able to write an algorithm rotating a matrix 3 times and keeping track of nodes at fixed indices. The same can be written for any type of Graph, using the node's visual coordinates instead of indices.

```kotlin
fun rotateMatrix(matrix: List<IntArray>): List<IntArray> {/*---*/}
val reflections = mutableListOf<Pair<Number, Number>>()
(0..2).fold(mat) { a, b ->
        val new = rotateMatrix(a)
        mat.forEachIndexed { x, e ->
            e.forEachIndexed { y, e2 ->
                reflections.add(mat[x][y] to new[x][y])
            }
        }
        new
    }
```

The result is a relationship describing that (0,2,8,6) are the "same"; (1,5,3,7) are the same etc. The only thing left to do is to use the output to determine which pairs of nodes correspond to which reflective siblings.